# Single word request: to learn or the act/state of learning something without awareness that one is being taught

Tags: single-word-requests

You'll often hear people reference how they learned so much about something, but it didn't *feel* like they were learning. Is there a word to describe this?

Sample sentence:
"I had no idea how much I learned from the trip to the planetarium. It was _____."

Comment: I can tell you the words that fit in the blank space and convey the meaning but they are not restricted to learning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are describing is called [***osmosis***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/osmosis):

> a process of absorption or diffusion suggestive of the flow of osmotic action; *especially* :  a usually effortless often unconscious assimilation
>
> *She seems to learn foreign languages by osmosis.*

[Merriam-Webster]

The word 'osmosis' has its origins in biology, describing the natural tendency for water to flow from areas of low concentration to high concentration in cells. The underlying idea is that it is a form of passive diffusion, in which no work has to be done by the cell.

Its adjective form is ***osmotic***, and its adverb form ***osmotically***. I'm not sure how often these constructions are seen in typical speech, however.

Comment: Exactly the word I would have suggested. I can't think of one more apt.